# Can I use AMP webpage if I have a template that multiple companies use?

Tags: css, amp-html

I am remaking my companies website template that our sub companies use. The question I have is that if each company has different colors and all the content is generated based on the company is it possible to use AMP? From what I read I can't use external css and that is very important because of company colors and some like different fonts and sizes.

Comment: please clarify the acronym AMP.  what did you read that said you can't use external css, why?  are you running the same set of code but altering it based on login or domain name?

Comment: You can make different amp pages for each company. Just link to the specific company amp page in the specific company header and back with a canonical link. The url can be adjusted based on a variable that is unique to that individual company